I would like to load an entire library into memory on android. What is the easiest way of doing this?
So I would like the entire library to be paged into memory not just mapped would System.load() achieve this? Or would the classes/methods need to be called? Is there a better way of doing this?
If there is no all in one solution, would invoking Classloaders to load the classes page the code for the classes into memory or just map them?
Anything pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, I read the Oracle and IBM docs and couldn't work out whether System.load actually loaded the library into memory.
Memory dumped process of app. Then attempted to load an .aar file that had been stored on the emulator with System.load, the app keeps crashing though, I think I might have to use DEXClassLoader, but want to be sure I'm not barking up the wrong tree. I'm trying to locate the library in memory.

WHy are you trying to do this?  What are you attempting to accomplish?  Mapped vs actually present in RAM is an OS level consideration, not something any app knows or needs to know.

Also, why are you trying to load an aar file?  You load .so files.  AAR files are completely different and are not linked to at runtime.  They're compiled into your apk/aab

@GabeSechan I'd like to get a memory dump of a whole library and convert it into an image. I'm pretty sure what I'll actually need to do is load individual classes into memory and dump them and then create the library from that.

Convert it into an image?  That doesn't really make sense. How would you convert random bytes in memory to an image and have it make any form of sense?  And loading a class has nothing to do with loading a library into memory.  I don't think you actually fully understand what you're asking, which makes answering difficult.

@GabeSechan I'm not saying the image would make sense to a human, but potentially the image would allow a machine to learn to recognize, whether a certain library was used by an application, based on it's memory during runtime. I know they're not really related. Easiest would be to load the whole library into memory, but this might not work since that's not really how libraries are used.

If you're looking for whether a .so file is loaded into memory, the easiest thing to do is to have the OS report when a .so file is loaded.  If you're looking for a .aar file, that wouldn't be possible since its not a linked library its built into the app statically.  In either case I see no way that looking at what memory positions are loaded would be of any help, since that wouldn't be the same device to device.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
